# Can Amaterasu's speed increase?

Tags: naruto

In the battle against Raikage, Sasuke cast Amaterasu and Raikage avoided it pretty easily because he's fast.
In the battle against Kaguya, Sasuke cast Amaterasu and it hit her.

**Question**
Was it because:
- Sasuke Amaterasu speed had increased as he grew stronger so Kaguya couldn't dodge?
- Kaguya could dodge it but she simply took it because she knew it was a chakra that she could absorb?

Are there any information about this?

Note: Kaguya is faster than Raikage, right?

Answer (score 3):

***Short Answer***: [Kaguya Otsutsuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) was very powerful but her speed was just slightly above average. During her [battle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reSSnNOGX5g) with Sasuke and Naruto, all she mainly did was hop from dimension to dimension, use a bunch of [Kekkai Moras](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kekkei_M%C5%8Dra)   and absorb their attacks with her Rinnengan. **Note that she is NOT faster than Raikage Ai when he uses the Lightning release chakra Mode** to enhance his speed and reaction time. The only reason why Raikage could dodge it is cause he combined 2 Jutsus simultenously in order to detect and flicker away from the flames. Kaguya on the other hand, was not fast enough to dodge the flames. However, she was skilled enough to quickly absorb them before they did enough damage on her.

So to answer your question, the speed of Amaterasu was never increased, She just was not fast enough to dodge the flames like Raikage did.

***Super Long explanation:***

The Amaterasu is a very fast jutsu in terms of how long it takes before it is cast. Unlike other jutsu, all it requires is that you see the person you want to hit and then  [Black Flames](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu) are ignited at the focal point of the target! This means that as long as the user can see you, the Amaterasu is most likely going to hit. In order to dodge an **"accurately-aimed" Amaterasu**, I believe the persons speed must be pretty close to that of light because the focal point of vision is directly what your eyes see from the refraction of light. (Its a completely different scenario if the user is partially blind and can't aim well.)
[image: Check the Shu guys comment]

In the case of Raikage, he used 2 jutsu's simultaneously in order to dodge sasukes Amaterasu. The first one is the lightning release chakra mode. During his battle with Sasuke, Raikage was wraped in lightning during the entire fight and once sasuke started to use the mangekyou Sharingan, Raikage instinctively started using way more chakra for the  [Lightning Release Chakra Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Release_Chakra_Mode) in order to increase his already heightened speed and reaction time.

[image: Lightning mode body flicker]

With enhanced speed and reaction time, Raikage was able to immediately react to sasuke's amaterasu, he then used the  ShunShin no jutsu ( Lightning release [Body Flicker technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Flicker_Technique) ). Since he combined the 2 jutsus perfectly, he was able to instantly react to and swiftly move away from the flames (***all within a matter of seconds, simply mindblowing lol***). Moreover, Kaguya could not pull such a feat.

Answer (score 1):

Speed is just a vague concept while using Amaterasu.

The real answer to this is accuracy. While fighting Sasuke, Itachi missed the Amaterasu several times. Not because Sasuke was running at the speed of light, but because of his blurry vision, which could not target Sasuke properly.

It could be that Sasuke missed casting it on the Raikage because he wasn't as proficient with it as he was while fighting Kaguya. His visual prowess was also enhanced and his vision was clearer because of the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan while fighting Kaguya.

So, the speed of the jutsu could increase (time taken to cast the jutsu, not reach the object) after unlocking the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan.

Comment: if you look at when sasuke aimed for raikage, he didn't miss the target. His aim was spot on. raikage was just way faster. The speed of amaterasu can't be increased because it doesn't take any time to cast the jutsu. As long as you can see the user and you activate the justsu then it immidiately starts burning. Plus the only difference between eternal mangekyou and normal mangekyou is that the eternal mangekyous light never runs out. The anime never talks about added abilities that come with the eternal mangekyou. Its just that its a more everlasting version of the mangekyou sharingan

Comment: That's my point.Eternal Mangekyou means clearer vision-which increases the accuracy of the jutsu.Obito,Itachi,Madara have themselves stated many times that with the Eternal Mangekyou,they have better chakra control.

Comment: Obito never stated that cause he never obtained eternal to begin with. and also can you show (cite me a source). Like a manga pic or Anime episode where that was said

Comment: This is just a vague statement like the question you asked,Anime Scientist where Kakashi "compliments" Naruto

Comment: Also,if Obito never obtained the EMS,why didn't the anime show him losing his vision?He had so many eyes to begin with,he used many of them for Izanagi(Vs Konan) and he used Kamui endlessly without any difficulty.

Comment: In Order to get an EMS Obito would have needed the mangekyou of a sibling, and Obitos family was never elaborated on in Naruto so I'm guessing  his situation was similar to Narutos. Also, I doubt he could get Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan with just one Mangekyou, I think thats because the Sharingan is a pair Dojutsu

Comment: That's not true.To awaken the Mangekyou,I agree someone close to the person,like a family member is required.But to obtain the EMS,you just need a spare pair of Sharingan.

Comment: If he did not awaken EMS,can you explain why his vision never blurred?

Comment: I guess its cause Obito already had senjuu blood or something, Cause if it were just possible to obtain EMS from a normal Mangekyou then why didn't danzou make shisuis eye an ems with the amount of sharingans that he had?

Comment: even Itachi stated while he was fighting Sasuke that he needed the mangekyou of a blood relative. You know Itachi was very smart right? why do you think he would prefer to be partially blind if he could have just easily attained the mangekyou of any of the people he killed, watch episode 134 to 139, the explanation is somewhere there

Comment: if Obito had Senju blood,he would have Rinnegan in both his eyes(Senju+Uchiha=Rinnegan).Itachi did not obtain EMS because he just did not want to.There is a question on that topic here as well.

Comment: obito had senjuu blood actually, the mere fact that he had zetsu's skin implanted into the right half of his body is proof that he had senjuu blood because white zetsu was cultivated from hashiramas cells. Also one needs ems to evolve to rinnegan, a mere sharingan or mangekyou can't evolve to rinnegan without the ems, check my answer: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48995/would-naruto-awaken-rinnegan-if-he-take-sharingan-from-sasuke/48997#48997

Comment: Assuming you are correct about having just Uchiha and senju bloodline to create the Rinnengan, then can you explain why Danzou sharingans did NOT all evolve to rinnengan. If that theory was 100% the truth then all the sharingans on Danzous hand and shisuis eyes would have all evolved to rinnengan when he got hasirama's cells implanted into him right?

Comment: Danzo was never an Uchiha to begin with.He had no Uchiha blood.So he couldn't unlock his Rinnegan.Also,White Zetsu was NOT CULTURED with Hashirama cells.It was the remnants of the people from the previous Infinite Tsukoyomi.Here's some evidence:https://youtu.be/8tXFWSzWcmU

Comment: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Zetsu white zetsu is one of the remnants of Kaguyas infinite tsukinomi, after madara summoned the gedo statue, black zetsu took out white zetsu and another one, tobi. Also, the eye of an uchiha contains their DNa, and white zetsu has hashimramas cells, Senju dna and chakra